# How to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on the same hard drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, wubi

After being away from Linux based machines for a long time, I've recently come into possession of an ASUS X551MA running an Intel Celeron N2830 @ 2.16 with 4 GB of RAM and a 500GM HD. I decided that I wanted to get back into dual booting on my school PC for fun, and now find myself wondering how the hell to do it properly.

I used to run Wubi on one of my old PCs, but, when I updated to Windows 8 everything went out the window.

My question is, I guess, firstly is it possible for me to either run Wubi on this machine with Windows 8.1, or, secondly, if that's not possible is there another method which I could use to dual boot 8.1/Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install 14.04 (64 bit) on a Toshiba NB10t-A with very similar specifications. I did it with a live CD. And after fiddling around a bit... I was able to get Grub to load up when my computer booted and I was in business. This involved switching from UEFI mode, to the other mode (I forget the precise name of it, for the life of me), which didn't work... and so I then switched back to UEFI mode, which caused Grub to spontaneously start working. [These](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) are the instructions I followed.

You might want to deviate from these particular instructions just a  bit, I'm not a fan of how they prompt you to partition your hard drive when installing Ubuntu, but other than that... they should send you well on your way.

Feel free to contact me directly or comment here if you have questions about how I did a particular step, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, yes, it is possible to run Wubi but it is neither recommended nor officially supported.

I found [a post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251986&s=8c3c0d8977c3e156ba34ffce488cf8dd&p=13162861#post13162861) of user hakuna_matata with a workaround for Wubi 14.10. It is too difficult for me to understand hakuna_matata's post. But there is also a link to [a dropbox folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na?dl=0).

I decided to use wubi1410SB.exe of this folder because it seemed to me the most powerful version of the folder. Maybe, it was not a good idea to download an unsigned .exe file but this patched version worked like a charm on my system (Windows 8.1, 64bit, UEFI)